# Running multiple docker containers using docker-compose causes hang on stdout for a different application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stdout, execv

I have a unique problem. Here is my setup:

1. I have a c application which calls a shell script through execv():

```
     char * const * parmList=(char * const *)data; // shell script is /root/test.sh
     if(pipe(pipes) == -1)
     {
        perror("Error creating pipe");
        free(output);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     else
     {
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if (pid  == -1)
        {
            perror("Error in fork");
        }
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            dup2(pipes[1],1);
            close(pipes[0]);
            close(pipes[1]);
            if(execv(parmList[0], parmList) == -1)
            {
                perror("Error in execv");
                free(output);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if(pid > 0)
        {
            close(pipes[1]);
            if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0)>0)
            {
                rc = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                int nbytes = read(pipes[0], output, 10000);
                output[nbytes]='\0';
                close(pipes[0]);
                strcpy(resultStr,(char *)output);
            }
        }
     }
     free(output);
```

2. All that shell script does is to cat an XML file which has large data. The value of data is XML file is around 6000 characters long.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /root/file.xml
```

3. I have four docker containers running using two compose files. Sample of one of the compose file is as follows:

```
version: '2.2'
services:

     test-compose1:
         image: test-image
         container_name: web_container1
         privileged: true
         network_mode: "host"
         volumes:
          - "/usr/:/usr/"
          - "/var/:/var/"
          - "/tmp/:/tmp/"
          - "/etc/:/etc/"
          - "/usr/local/thirdparty/jakarta-tomcat/lib/:/opt/APACHE_TOMCAT/lib/"
          - "/home/tomcat/server_webapps.xml:/home/tomcat/server.xml"
          - "/home/tomcat/start_webapps.sh:/home/tomcat/start.sh"
          - "/home/tomcat/context.xml:/opt/APACHE_TOMCAT/conf/context.xml"

     test-compose2:
         image: test-image
         container_name: web_container2
         privileged: true
         network_mode: "host"
         volumes:
          - "/usr/:/usr/"
          - "/var/:/var/"
          - "/tmp/:/tmp/"
          - "/etc/:/etc/"
          - "/usr/local/thirdparty/jakarta-tomcat/lib/:/opt/APACHE_TOMCAT/lib/"
          - "/home/tomcat/server_webapps.xml:/home/tomcat/server.xml"
          - "/home/tomcat/start_webapps.sh:/home/tomcat/start.sh"
          - "/home/tomcat/context.xml:/opt/APACHE_TOMCAT/conf/context.xml"
```

So, like I said I have two compose files. The other compose file is similar to the one above. And all four containers are running an instance of tomcat within each. Nothing fancy. So, when I do a docker-compose up, I have four containers running in total.

**Issue**: with the above setup, if I start my c application it simply hangs at the cat command. I have tried all possible hacks like increasing the buffer size, flushing the stdout. Nothing seems to work. GDB shows that the application is simply stuck at write() system call.

Now, the most interesting part:

-If the docker containers are NOT running, the application (cat command) works just fine. It doesn't hang at 'cat command'

-If I have just TWO containers running instead of four, the application works just fine. It doesn't hang at 'cat command'

-With all the four containers running, if I used system() API instead of execv() in the above c code, it seems to work just fine. It doesn't hang at 'cat command'

-With all the four containers running, if I use an XML file with smaller data, it works just fine.

-If I start all four of the docker containers using "docker run" command instead of docker-compose, it works just fine. It doesn't hang at 'cat command'

So, I am perplexed about how the docker containers are affecting the cat command to hang at stdout. This seems something to do with the docker-compose environment. But, I am not sure what really is wrong. I have hit a dead-end in debugging this.

Any pointers on how to debug this?

Comment: Your parent process isn't `read()`ing anything until the child process has exited; but the child can't exit until it has `write()`d the entire file.  You need to read the content first, possibly in a `select()` loop.

Comment: The code is intentionally written that way. To maintain consistency, I would like the child to exit once it has written data fully. This code is working perfectly fine without those docker containers(more than 2). So, I would like to get to the bottom of why/how docker containers are affecting write to stdout???